# mysql: select, insert, delete and update in one query

Tags: mysql

i need in one query use select, insert, delete and update.

(I need copy data from old table in to new, then delete old, and update another).

Insert and select (copy function I was able to, but now i have problem)

I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO news_n (id, data)
    SELECT (id, data)
    FROM news
    WHERE id > 21
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the error? You can not use the same table to perform multiple operations, i.e. `SELECT` with `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it all in one ***query***, but you can do it all in one ***transaction*** if you are using a transactional store engine (like InnoDB). This might be what you want, but it's hard to tell only using the information you provided in your question.

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT...;
DELETE...
UPDATE...;

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 2):

In one query i dont think its possible.

You can try writing a Stored Procedure and using Triggers you may achieve that

Answer (score 1):

`MySQL` does not support `MERGE`, so you'll have to do it in two queries:

```
INSERT
INTO    news_n (id, data)
SELECT  id, data
FROM    news
WHERE   id > 21
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
SET     data = news.data

DELETE
FROM    news_n
WHERE   id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    news
        WHERE   id > 21
        )
```

, provided you have `PRIMARY KEY (id)` in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine Select/Update/etc into one query. You will have to write separate queries for each operation you intend to complete.