# Update many-to-many relation table without violating primay contraint

Tags: mysql, sql

Considering two tables with a many-to-many relation :

```
Company           Speciality
---------         ---------
id                id
---------         ---------
1                 21
2                 22
3                 23
4


CompanySpeciality
--------------------------
company_id | speciality_id
--------------------------
1          | 21
1          | 22
4          | 21
4          | 23
```

I want to delete company 4, and associate its specialities to the company 1.
If I use a simple UPDATE statement on CompanySpeciality to set "company_id = 1 WHERE company_id=4", I'm facing the primary contraint violation because the pair 1|21 already exists.

Is the a way to update the relation table with a single query ? This query should only affect rows that will not be duplicated.

The result would be :

```
CompanySpeciality
--------------------------
company_id | speciality_id
--------------------------
1          | 21
1          | 22
1          | 23
```

Comment: Because company 4 don't have always the same specialities as company 1. I want to merge specialities from company_1 and company_4 into company_1, and then delete company_4

Comment: Okay, I've updated your example slightly to make this clearer... can you double check please?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I've added an exemple for the expected result. Note that it's not a problem if the "problematic" pair 4 | 21 stays in the table, I can run a cleanup task to remove orphans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to `UPDATE`, you want to [`INSERT` and ignore dupes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO CompanySpeciality (company_id, speciality_id)
SELECT 1, speciality_id
FROM CompanySpeciality
WHERE company_id=4
```

Comment: it won't work. You'll need to change your SELECT company_id, ... to SELECT 1, speciality_id

Comment: Ok, I never used a kind of "insert ingnore" statement before. It looks interesting but as galchen said, I think you're missing a part of the query no ? Nothing about the key "1" ?

Comment: just a word of caution: be sure you get your datatypes correct when using `INSERT IGNORE`.  if you try to enter something with this statement that doesn't match the datatype of the field, it won't fail.  it'll just convert your input "to the closest value" (see link above), which may not be what you want.  sometimes you might prefer the error to the guess.

Answer (score 2):

something to the effect of:

```
UPDATE CompanySpecialty
SET company_id=1
WHERE company_id=4
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CompanySpecialty cs WHERE cs.company_id=1 AND cs.specialty_id=CompanySpecialty.specialty_id);
```

should work for you.  (i haven't tested the exact syntax, but using a `NOT EXISTS` clause should help you eliminate the problem of violating primary key restraints).

you will then have to remove the extra records left in the table for company 4 in a separate query:

```
DELETE FROM CompanySpecialty
WHERE company_id=4;
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

you won't be able to both update and delete records in a single query. You can use transactions:

[mysql: select, insert, delete and update in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089140/mysql-select-insert-delete-and-update-in-one-query)