# Updating a set of data (delete some entries and add some) in the database using a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose I have a Product that can be associated with `k` categories. Simplified DB Structure:

```
// Table for products
product
- pid
- name

// Table for categories
category
- cid
- name

// table associating a product with categories
product_category
- pcid
- pid
- cid
```

Assuming the current system state has the product already associated with a set of categories. Ex

```
Product: Dell XPS Laptop
Categories: Laptop, Electronics, Dell
```

Later, the admin submits an updated set of categories that removes `Dell` from the product and adds `Computers`. The admin can also remove  more than one and add more than one category at any time.

I can do this operation using 2 steps by one of several methods including:

1. Delete all categories for a product, and add the ones in the new set
2. Retrieve all current categories, compare it to the new set of categories; then run a delete and insert query as necessary.

***Question:***

Is there a way to do a delete and update at the same time **using a single query**? asking MySQL to check this new set, delete what are existing but not in the new set and add the non-existent categories?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089140/mysql-select-insert-delete-and-update-in-one-query)

You can create a [Stored Procedure](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,358569) and

execute it in a single query.

Regards.