# update the link table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm validating following SQL approach from the community where I'm completely updating the user's roles. (Full update of the join table)

**User**

```
+----+-------+------+
| id | first | last |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 | John  | Doe  |
|  2 | Jane  | Doe  |
+----+-------+------+
```

**Role**

```
+----+----------+
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | admin    |
|  2 | accounts |
|  3 | sales    |
+----+----------+
```

**UserRole**

```
+--------+--------+
| userid | roleid |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |      1 |
|      1 |      2 |
|      1 |      3 |
|      2 |      2 |
|      2 |      3 |
+--------+--------+
```

My SQL approach -> first delete all, second insert all records

```
DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE userid = 1;
INSERT INTO UserRole(userid, roleid) VALUES(1, 2), (1, 3);
```

Is there a better way? I mean to do this in a single query possibly for these sorts of linking/join tables?

**Edit**

I think what I should have said to find an efficient SQL operation instead of a single query.

Here's another SQL

```
DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE user_id = 1 AND role_id NOT IN (2, 3);
INSERT INTO UserRole(user_id, role_id) VALUES(1, 2), (1, 3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id = VALUES(user_id), role_id = VALUES(role_id);
```

Comment: You mean  `WHERE userid = 1`, right?

Comment: Your method seems good to me.

Comment: I don't think you really need to do in single query.  [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143637/insert-and-delete-in-single-operation-moving-from-one-table-to-other)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4089692/8484512)

Comment: Just for fun :) `DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE userid = 1 AND roleid NOT IN (2,3);`

Comment: please see Edit section.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add all roles for all users into the userRoles table, you can delete from userRoles, then recreate table like below:

```
DECLARE @users TABLE ( userID INT, UserName NVARCHAR(MAX) )
DECLARE @roles TABLE ( roleID INT, RoleName NVARCHAR(MAX) )
DECLARE @userRoles TABLE ( userID INT, roleID INT )

INSERT INTO @users (userID,UserName) VALUES (1,'name1'),(2,'name2'),(3,'name3')
INSERT INTO @roles (roleID,RoleName) VALUES (1,'admin'),(2,'accounts'),(3,'sales')

INSERT INTO @userRoles (userID,roleID)
SELECT U.userID,R.roleID FROM @users U
FULL OUTER JOIN @roles R ON 1=1
ORDER BY userID

SELECT * FROM @userRoles
```

OUTPUT:

```
userID  roleID
1   1
2   1
3   1
1   2
2   2
3   2
1   3
2   3
3   3
```